# Last scrape of Prometheus

Tags: prometheus

I have configured Prometheus and state of all configured endpoints i.e. clients are up. All job's scrape interval is kept 5 second. But when checked in the column "Last Scrape" , I see last scrape 1 hr few min. ago. or few min. ago. Does that mean something going wrong. How does scrape in Prometheus works.

Thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmMeL.jpg)

Comment: added image of prometheus.yml, I have replaced hostnames for security reasons.